# Th doesn't sort Tbody on some modified column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have multiple `tbody` in a table which some of span columns and rows. And then I got a jQuery code to sort this `tbody` based on the `th.data`- click.

In the first `th` column when it is clicked it will sort correctly. However, in the second `th` column when it is clicked it does not sort the `tbody`.

Here is the snippet :

```js
var table = $('table'),
    th = table.find('thead th'),
    tbody = table.find('tbody');


$(th).on('click', function() {
    
    $(th).removeClass();
    
    var index = this.cellIndex,
        sortType = $(this).data('sort'),
        sortDir  = $(this).data('dir') || 'asc';
    

  var that = $(this);

    $('table').find('tbody').slice().sort(function(a, b) {
    
      var dataTH = that.data('class'); 
        
        //alert(dataTH);
    
      if(dataTH == 'number')
         {
            //alert("hi this is a number");
            var aText = $(a).find('td.sortNum:eq(' + index + ')').text(),
                bText = $(b).find('td.sortNum:eq(' + index + ')').text();          
          }
          
      else if(dataTH == 'department')
         {
            //alert("hi this is a department");
            var aText = $(a).find('td.depart:eq(' + index + ')').text(),
                bText = $(b).find('td.depart:eq(' + index + ')').text();          
          }
    
            if (sortDir == 'desc') {
                temp = aText;
                aText = bText;
                bText = temp;
            }
            
            if (sortType == 'string') {
                return aText.localeCompare(bText);    
            }

      else {
                return +aText - +bText;
            }
        })
        .appendTo('table');

    $(this).data('dir', sortDir == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('sort-' + sortDir);

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 400px;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px #DDD solid;
}

.sort-asc:after,
.sort-desc:after {
    content: '▲';
    font-size: 12px;
}
.sort-desc:after {
    content: '▼';
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-sort="number" data-class="number" >No</th>
            <th data-sort="number" data-class="department" >Department</th>
            <th data-sort="number">Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="sortNum">1</td>
            <td class="depart">20</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">VTP</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="sortNum">2</td>
            <td class="depart">30</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">VTP</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="sortNum">3</td>
            <td class="depart">40</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">VTP</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="sortNum">4</td>
            <td class="depart">50</td>
            <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">VTP</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="sortNum">5</td>
            <td class="depart">60</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">VTP</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>


    
    
</table>
```

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Klaudia/331rzz85/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `:eq` Selector since you are referencing the Cells by css class. It does work in the first Column because the cell index is zero. What you are essentially saying in the selector `$(a).find('td.sortNum:eq(' + index + ')')` is "give me the list of td's with the class 'sortNum' and of that list the element at position `index`. But the first condition of the Selector - td.sortNum - will only return one element.

To make your sorting work again for the second column you could get rid of the `:eq` part

```
    if(dataTH == 'number')
    {
        //alert("hi this is a number");
        var aText = $(a).find('td.sortNum').text(),
            bText = $(b).find('td.sortNum').text();          
    }
    else if(dataTH == 'department')
    {
        //alert("hi this is a department");
        var aText = $(a).find('td.depart').text(),
            bText = $(b).find('td.depart').text();          
    }
```

see also http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/Lvvmow8g/1/